# Variable as static function

Tags: php

I have a class Sections:

```
class Sections {
    public static function get($name) {
        //
    }
}
```

And I would like to call the static function get() from it with a variable (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
$section = 'Sections::get';
$section('body');
```

But it gives me a Fatal error: Call to undefined function Sections::get()

Is it possible to call a static function in this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the class separately from the method:

```
$class = 'Sections';
$method = 'get';
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
$class::$method('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `call_user_func` to do this:

```
$section = array('Sections', 'get');
call_user_func($section, 'body');
```

Or:

```
$section = 'Sections::get';
call_user_func($section, 'body');
```

Comment: A problem that I see with your solution is that in stacktraces you'll only see `call_user_func()` but not `Sections::get()` which makes the trace less worth for debugging. That's why I try to avoid `call_user_func()` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with the help of a function outside of the class:

```
class Sections {
    public static function get($name) {
        //
    }
}

function section($name) {
    Sections::get($name);
}
```

Now I can do:

```
$section = 'section';
$section('body');
```